# How can I build OpenCover, and update it to .NET 4.5.1?

Tags: .net, updates, opencover

I've been using OpenCover as part of a project, and one of the pieces of software I need to cover is targeting .NET 4.5.1. However, OpenCover is targeting .NET 4.0. This is causing a problem with the software we're trying to test, because it expects to be running .NET 4.5.1 and OpenCover seems to make it think it's running .NET 4.0.

I've downloaded the OpenCover source code to try to update it to .NET 4.5.1 on my own, but I haven't even been able to get it to build in .NET 4.0. The documentation found [here](https://github.com/opencover/opencover) wasn't clear enough to help me build it on my own. So, the main part of my question is, does anyone have any experience building OpenCover from source, and can you provide me with a clear set of instructions on how to do so? The research and multiple attempts I've tried have so far yielded no results. Additionally, if anyone has tried to update OpenCover to .NET 4.5.1, I'd be interested in hearing whatever information you've gathered there.

EDIT:

Here's a bit more information on what I've done to get it to build:

I ran the Build.bat file included in the source code. It runs fine for a few seconds, then outputs:

"BUILD FAILED

External Program Failed: C:\Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/MSBuild.exe (return code was 1)"

Hopefully that will give you some more insight into the problem I'm experiencing.

EDIT 2:

Thanks to Patrick Hofman, I was pointed in the right direction and managed to change the version of MSBuild.exe to the correct one and stopped that error. Unfortunately, I'm now getting some kind of linking error, the full text of which can be seen in the pastebin in the comment on Patrick's answer below:

```
 [exec] "C:\Users\scogan\Source\Repos\OpenCover\main\OpenCover.Test.Profiler\OpenCover.Test.Profiler.vcxproj" (Rebuild target) (15:2) ->
 [exec] (Link target) ->
 [exec]   gtestd.lib(gtest-all.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_MSC_VER': value '1700' doesn't match value '1800' in ExceptionHandler.obj [C:\Users\scogan\Source\Repos\OpenCover\main\OpenCover.Test.Profiler\OpenCover.Test.Profiler.vcxproj]
 [exec]   gtest_maind.lib(gtest_main.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_MSC_VER': value '1700' doesn't match value '1800' in ExceptionHandler.obj [C:\Users\scogan\Source\Repos\OpenCover\main\OpenCover.Test.Profiler\OpenCover.Test.Profiler.vcxproj]
 [exec]   C:\Users\scogan\Source\Repos\OpenCover\main\bin\Debug\OpenCover.Test.Profiler.exe : fatal error LNK1319: 2 mismatches detected [C:\Users\scogan\Source\Repos\OpenCover\main\OpenCover.Test.Profiler\OpenCover.Test.Profiler.vcxproj]
```

Comment: "I haven't even been able to get it to build": I suggest you provide more details where you got stuck specifically - your odds to get helpful advice will only increase.

Comment: You're definitely right. I'll edit the question and provide some more details.

Comment: Are you on a 64 bit machine? Does the file `C:\Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/MSBuild.exe` exist? Is there a log file with the output of the build process?

Comment: I am on a 64 bit machine, and the MSBuild.exe file does exist in the specified location. As far as an actual log file, I don't see one that is generated, but I'll try to pipe it to a text file and pastebin it for you.

Comment: Here's the output:

http://pastebin.com/pKUmW9ui

Comment: @SeanCogan I can't see pastebin from work :-/

Comment: [OpenCover](https://github.com/OpenCover/opencover) shouldn't AFIAK affect the runtime your application runs on as it launches it using [Process.Start ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4h05yb(v=vs.110).aspx) so you application should be running as it's own process. Perhaps you should raise an [issue](https://github.com/OpenCover/opencover/issues) and the team who are much more use to the code base (and is quite active) may be able to help.

Comment: Hmm, ok, thanks Shaun. I saw your other comment, too, and you've been very helpful. I'll pass this information onto the team that develops the software we're using OpenCover on to see if they have any other ideas as to what could be causing this issue.

I don't know if this matters, but the issue being thrown is "System.InvalidProgramException: Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program." Does that change anything?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because the issues I've been having extend past the scope of this question, and most of the discussion had here doesn't really help to solve the underlying problem I'm having. Thanks for everyone's help, though.

Answer (score 2):

So, the actual error message in the log is:

> error MSB8020: The builds tools for v120 (Platform Toolset = 'v120') cannot be found. To build using the v120 build tools, either click the Project menu or right-click the solution, and then select "Update VC++ Projects...". Install v120 to build using the v120 build tools.

I guess you didn't install the VC++ tools when installing Visual Studio.

Comment: That would probably be it! I think I only have the C# tools, since that's what I do most of my work in. Let me try to install those and see if that works.

Comment: Ok, so I think I've already got the VC++ tools, but this I think the error you posted is being caused by the changes made to MSBuild discussed in this article: http://timrayburn.net/blog/visual-studio-2013-and-msbuild/

So I guess I just need to somehow change the path that the built.bat file is using for MSBuild?

Comment: I was able to switch over to the correct version of MSBuild, but unfortunately I'm getting a new error.

http://pastebin.com/SKE5e92q

It seems to be an issue with the Test solutions only, so I'm trying to remove them entirely without much success.

Comment: Well, through some unholy magicks, I was able to get OpenCover to build on .NET 4.0, and it actually runs. There was a lot of cutting stuff out and adding stuff to make certain errors go away in various .build and .proj files. I'm going to leave this question open so I can put a bounty on it and hopefully get some more information, though, because I'm sure there was a better way to do this, and I still need it to build on .NET 4.5.1.

Comment: We currently use VS2012 to compile OpenCover, we compile on .NET4 but should be able to handle the other runtimes as it is the profiler (via the [profiler API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404511(v=vs.110).aspx)) that hooks into the runtime. we support 4.5.1 (ICorProfilerCallback5) but I see that a new interface has created for 4.5.2 - ICorProfilerCallback6 - I wonder perhaps if this is the cause of your woes.